# How many squares can I select from chess board

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, chessboard

I am given an $n\times n$ chess board. I have to select $k$ squares of size $1\times1$ so that no two squares share a common side. I have tried for $2\times2 , 3\times3 $ but for big values of $n$ can anyone give an approach to solve this type of problem or suggest any resources about this type of problems?

ex:

For $n=2, k=1$ there are $4$ ways.

For $n=2 ,k=2$ there are $2$ ways.

Comment: Why aren't there $2$ ways for $n=2,k=2$? You can choose either pair of squares that are diagonally opposite.

Comment: yeah sorry my mistake , i updated

Comment: Also "select $k$ squares" you mean only $1\times1$ squares, right? You can't select a $2\times2$ square? (otherwise $n=2,k=1$ would have $5$ possibilities)

Comment: k squares means 1*1 only .. sorry for my poor explanation

Comment: we can select any square of size 1*1  ,i.e( either black or white )

Comment: I don't think there will be a simple answer.  Of course, for $k=1$ you have $n^2$ choices.  For $k=2$ you would have $\frac 12n^2(n^2-1)$ choices if you didn't worry about them touching, so you can subtract the $2n(n-1)$ touching pairs (select the left one or the top one in $n(n-1)$ ways).  When you get to $k=3$ it is hard to count the disallowed sets.

Comment: For $n$ odd and $k=(n^2+1)/2$ , there is $1$ choice. For $n$ even and $k=n^2/2$ there are $2$ choices

Comment: I think that in general for $k=n^2/2$ there are $2$ ways.